# How can I extract the names of games of which I added shortcuts to Steam from a shortcuts.vdf file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, regex

I am trying to put together an excel sheet that lists all the games that I have added shortcuts to Steam. Steam lets you add shortcuts to non-steam games and acts as a launcher for them. The shortcut links that the user adds are in a local database called shortcuts.vdf, which contains all the information relevant to the games Steam has. All I'm basically interested in is the names of the games.

Here is a snippet of what the data in the file looks like in notepad:

```
shortcuts  0 appid °rõÄappname Cemu Exe "T:\Cemu\App+Update+DLC\Cemu.exe" StartDir "T:\Cemu\App+Update+DLC\" icon  ShortcutPath  LaunchOptions  IsHidden     AllowDesktopConfig    AllowOverlay    openvr     Devkit     DevkitGameID  LastPlayTime ZùÏ_ tags 0 favorite 1 All Games  1 appid }yâappname Citra Nightly Exe "C:\Users\phili\AppData\Local\Citra\nightly-mingw\citra-qt.exe" StartDir "C:\Users\phili\AppData\Local\Citra\nightly-mingw\" icon  ShortcutPath  LaunchOptions  IsHidden     AllowDesktopConfig    AllowOverlay    openvr     Devkit     DevkitGameID  LastPlayTime ¿
ã_ tags 0 favorite 1 All Games  2 appid {Sü¸appname RollerCoaster Tycoon 2: Triple Thrill Pack Open Exe "C:\Program Files\OpenRCT2\openrct2.exe" StartDir "C:\Program Files\OpenRCT2\" icon  ShortcutPath  LaunchOptions  IsHidden     AllowDesktopConfig    AllowOverlay    openvr     Devkit     DevkitGameID  LastPlayTime !Ý_ tags 0 steam 1 All Games  3 appid Iì»Âappname Art Of Fighting 2 Exe "R:\Amazon Games\Library\Art of Fighting 2\ArtOfFighting2.exe" StartDir "R:\Amazon Games\Library\Art of Fighting 2\" icon  ShortcutPath  LaunchOptions  IsHidden     AllowDesktopConfig    AllowOverlay    openvr     Devkit     DevkitGameID  LastPlayTime      tags 0 Shortcuts 1 Amazon 2 All Games  4 appid ñappname Origin Exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin\Origin.exe" StartDir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin\" icon  ShortcutPath  LaunchOptions  IsHidden     AllowDesktopConfig    AllowOverlay    openvr     Devkit     DevkitGameID  LastPlayTime ÛÊ*] tags 0 steam 1 All Games  5 appid £á@¤appname A Good Snowman Is Hard To Build Exe "R:\Amazon Games\Library\A Good Snowman Is Hard To Build\Snowman.exe" StartDir "R:\Amazon Games\Library\A Good Snowman Is Hard To Build\" icon  ShortcutPath  LaunchOptions  IsHidden     AllowDesktopConfig    AllowOverlay    openvr     Devkit     DevkitGameID  LastPlayTime      tags 0 Shortcuts 1 Amazon 2 All Games  6 appid ¢‡    æappname Adam Wolfe Exe "R:\Amazon Games\Library\Adam Wolfe\AdamWolfe.exe" StartDir "R:\Amazon
```

I noticed that the names of games that I added to Steam are always between the words `appname` and `Exe`, like this:

```
£á@¤appname A Good Snowman Is Hard To Build Exe
```

How can I modify/extract entries from that file so that I have an excel sheet that contains the entry between `appname` and `Exe` in one cell per row?

Like so:

[image: List of entries in excel sheet]

I was thinking about regular expressions maybe? I don't have Microsoft Office, only Libre Office

[Original shortcuts.vdf file upload + txt converted version.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/137G0JKhwMOVAmdKVFqwabOHC7tNbsILQ?usp=sharing)

Comment: As you have mentioned - `I don't have Microsoft Office, only Libre Office` , I assume you are on linux platform and so then you can try using grep, sed and awk to get the info. Try to get your hands dirty on it and you can definitely do it.

Comment: Could you please provide with the absolute path of the `shortcuts.vdf` file?

Comment: the absolute path of the file is: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\149576161\config\shortcuts.vdf"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be simple to achieve, all you need is PowerShell, no Office Suite is needed.

From the syntax of the paths, they start with a drive letter (i.e. T:) and use backslashes (`\`) to separate the directories, I assume you are on Windows.

You are on Windows, use this to open PowerShell:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>→type `PowerShell`→<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then once you are in PowerShell, you can use this regex to get the game names: `(appname)(.*?)(Exe)`

Steam .vdf format is a proprietary format, so it can be hard to properly parse the format, though you can probably use this:[GitHub:Steam-GetOnTop](https://github.com/ChiefIntegrator/Steam-GetOnTop), I don't use Steam, and I haven't used the package, so I don't guarantee it will work.

But since the file is encoded in plaintext, you can open it with notepad.exe, and all you need is the content between `appname` and `Exe`, you can use the brute force way:

```powershell
$shortcuts=((Get-Content "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\149576161\config\shortcuts.vdf").ToCharArray() | where{![char]::IsControl("$_")}) -join ""
($shortcuts | Select-String -pattern "(appname)(.*?)(Exe)" -AllMatches).matches.value | %{$_.Substring(7,$_.Length-10)} | sort-object | out-file "$([environment]::getfolderpath('desktop'))\gamename.txt"
```

Explanation:

Step 1: We get the content of the shortcuts.vdf, convert the string to character array, filter out Control Characters, and join into a string

Step 2: We print the content we get in the first step and pass it down the pipeline; We get the content from pipeline and select all strings that matches `(appname)(.*?)(Exe)`, and use `().matches.value` to get only the matches, then we get rid of `appname` and `Exe` and export it to a file named gamename.txt located on your desktop.

If you insist to export to a Excel sheet with only one column, though, use this:

```powershell
$shortcuts=((Get-Content "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\149576161\config\shortcuts.vdf").ToCharArray() | where{![char]::IsControl("$_")}) -join ""
($shortcuts | Select-String -pattern "(appname)(.*?)(Exe)" -AllMatches).matches.value | %{$_.Substring(7,$_.Length-10)} | sort-object | %{[PSCustomObject]@{GameName=$_}} | export-csv "$([environment]::getfolderpath('desktop'))\gamename.csv"
```

The method is almost the same with the first method, but we convert the results to `[PSCustomObject]` and export the final result to a .csv file located at path "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\gamename.csv" instead of a.txt file.

---

Further notes:

[Microsoft Docs:What is PowerShell?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-7.1)

[Microsoft Docs:About Variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.1)

[Microsoft Docs:About Foreach](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.1)

[Microsoft Docs:Everything you wanted to know about PSCustomObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.1)

[Microsoft Docs:Everything you wanted to know about arrays](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays?view=powershell-7.1)

[Microsoft Docs:About Arrays](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.1)

[Microsoft Docs:Get-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1)

[Microsoft Docs:Select-String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1)

[Microsoft Docs:Out-File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1)

[Microsoft Docs:Export-Csv](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.1)

---

### ***OutPut***

As you said ***it does not contain any personal information*** and attached the file to the question, I will post the result I get below:

***`Google Drive`***

Output of my first method:

[gamename.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1udILBaL3aJPv-ZmN_zuuhZD1GcYTOSvX/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Output of my second method:

[gamename.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rYfLQPkicSE37C4WRG1fAFG6ETKmoIag/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Output of the vbs method from the other answer:

[steam.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hQdqebmw705rM4f0FzxYT4R0AZ5x5PxG/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

---

### ***Code efficiency analysis***

The first method is 358 characters long

The second method is 396 characters long

The vbs script is 541 characters long

The first method golfed:

```powershell
$s=((gc "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\149576161\config\shortcuts.vdf").ToCharArray() | ?{![char]::IsControl("$_")}) -join ""
($s | sls "(appname)(.*?)(Exe)" -all).matches.value | %{$_.Substring(7,$_.Length-10)} | sort >"$([environment]::getfolderpath('desktop'))\gamename.txt"
```

286 characters long

The second method golfed:

```powershell
$s=((gc "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\149576161\config\shortcuts.vdf").ToCharArray() | ?{![char]::IsControl("$_")}) -join ""
($s | sls "(appname)(.*?)(Exe)" -all).matches.value | %{$_.Substring(7,$_.Length-10)} | sort | %{[PSCustomObject]@{GameName=$_}} | epcsv "$([environment]::getfolderpath('desktop'))\gamename.csv"
```

329 characters long

The vbs doesn't sort the results, nor does it automatically output to a file.

Below are the runtime tests:

```powershell
PS C:\Users\Estranger> measure-command {$s=((gc "C:\Users\Estranger\Downloads\shortcuts.vdf").ToCharArray() | ?{![char]::IsControl("$_")}) -join ""
>> ($s | sls "(appname)(.*?)(Exe)" -all).matches.value | %{$_.Substring(7,$_.Length-10)} | sort >"$([environment]::getfolderpath('desktop'))\gamename.txt"}

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 1
Milliseconds      : 86
Ticks             : 10863660
TotalDays         : 1.25736805555556E-05
TotalHours        : 0.000301768333333333
TotalMinutes      : 0.0181061
TotalSeconds      : 1.086366
TotalMilliseconds : 1086.366

PS C:\Users\Estranger> measure-command {$s=((gc "C:\Users\Estranger\Downloads\shortcuts.vdf").ToCharArray() | ?{![char]::IsControl("$_")}) -join ""
>> ($s | sls "(appname)(.*?)(Exe)" -all).matches.value | %{$_.Substring(7,$_.Length-10)} | sort | %{[PSCustomObject]@{GameName=$_}} | epcsv "$([environment]::getfolderpath('desktop'))\gamename.csv"}

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 1
Milliseconds      : 171
Ticks             : 11716488
TotalDays         : 1.356075E-05
TotalHours        : 0.000325458
TotalMinutes      : 0.01952748
TotalSeconds      : 1.1716488
TotalMilliseconds : 1171.6488

PS C:\Users\Estranger> measure-command {cscript steam.vbs}

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 1
Milliseconds      : 338
Ticks             : 13380483
TotalDays         : 1.54866701388889E-05
TotalHours        : 0.000371680083333333
TotalMinutes      : 0.022300805
TotalSeconds      : 1.3380483
TotalMilliseconds : 1338.0483
```

My first method obviously won, the downvote is unfair, the OP didn't post the critical information, so my code couldn't have solved the OP's problem at first no matter how good I am.

---

To whoever downvoted my answer, my answer is now edited and your downvote is no longer locked, please cast votes carefully based on objective facts, and please lift the downvote.

To the OP, the other answer is, objectively, not as efficient as my answer.
You didn't post the right information at first, so I only have incorrect information to work with. No matter how good I am, it is impossible for me to solve your problem because "Garbage In, Garbage Out", the other answerer just got lucky and happened to be online when you posted the right information while I was away, and you see the script is not as good as mine, please consider accept my answer instead.

---

Even shorter code:

Method 1 Golfed

```powershell
$s=((gc "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\149576161\config\shortcuts.vdf").ToCharArray() | ?{![char]::IsControl("$_")}) -join ""
($s | sls "(?<=appname)(.*?)(?=Exe)" -All).matches.value | sort > "$([environment]::getfolderpath('desktop'))\gamename.txt"
```

Method 2 Golfed

```powershell
$s=((gc "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\149576161\config\shortcuts.vdf").ToCharArray() | ?{![char]::IsControl("$_")}) -join ""
($s | sls "(?<=appname)(.*?)(?=Exe)" -All).matches.value | sort | %{[PSCustomObject]@{GameName=$_}} | epcsv "$([environment]::getfolderpath('desktop'))\gamename.csv"
```

The regex used by these new methods will matches only the game names, but using it increases runtime by 0.3s compared to the first regex.

This is what I see in console using the second method 1 golfed:
[image]

I want to answer this question and help the OP simply because I find the question interesting, the thing OP wanted is fun, I am just a beginner in Programming, and I want to improve my skills by answering questions others have posted with programs, that's all...

P.S. I really want to be a hacker...

Comment: I tried both methods. Unfortunately, the first one yields an error: `At line:3 char:84
+ ... name) {(7..($game.length-4)|%{[char[]]$game[$_]}) -join ""} | out-fil ...
+                                                                 ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement` the second one does nothing, nothing happens

Comment: I tested the regex in a google sheet and `(?<=\appname )(.*?)(?=\ Exe)` did highlight only the names of the games, whereas `appname[\s\S]+Exe` highlighted everything

Comment: there must be something wrong with the file because all I get is an empty output file or none at all. both of your methods plus the visual basic script method don't work. I even saved the `vdf` file as `.txt` - same thing: empty output. I have updated the original question and attached the `vdf` file to it, it does not contain any personal information. I must be doing something wrong

Comment: @Phil, your collection of games is missing a lot Assassin's Creed games and Anno games... Also, you said the file does not contain personal information, but from the names of games you have played alone, perverts can analyze what type of person you are, and use it for malicious purposes, fortunately I am not such pervert, I see a challenge to overcome, once it's done the job is done. You are not interesting to me, but there are many people who will find you interesting, next time be smarter:)

Comment: I did not downvote you as I would never downvote anyone who helps me. I tried all three methods and would have preferred the powershell/excel one but it just didn't work I copied the code you posted and even tried after installing the PS version you linked. That's why I uploaded the original file to see if the snippet might miss any information. Also this list is about 80% games that Epic and Amazon have given away for free which is a public list anyway :)

Comment: The first example you posted is wrong, because there aren't space characters between `Appname` `gamename` and `Exe`, but rather they are like this: "Appname`NUL`Assassin's Creed III`NULSOH`Exe", so the regex won't work. After you had posted the original file, I have made my code working, and perfected it, made it better than the vbs, please consider accept my answer.

Comment: I copied the code from both Method 1 Golfed and Method 2 Golfed into powershell ISE and powershell 7-preview, ran the code and on my desktop are now two empty files. You seem to be getting the list with the file I uploaded, so I am 100% sure it is on my end and that I'm doing something wrong. But still, it is just not working for me

Comment: Did you copy the last codes?

Comment: They wouldn't work, because I copy pasted the first line from ungolfed codes, of course they wouldn't work, I found it and fixed it, sorry :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118363/discussion-between-phil-and-xei-n).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very hacky bit of vbscript which essentially breaks down the `shortcuts.vdf` file into seperate lines (based on the `nul` character) and then spits out the next line after the one called `AppName`. I did try to just split `file` using `Chr(0)` as the delimiter but it threw an error .

Save the following file as `steam.vbs`:

```vb
Dim oFile: Set oFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile("shortcuts.vdf")
Dim file : file = oFile.OpenAsTextStream().Read(oFile.Size)

Dim content, i, c

For i = 1 To Len(file)
    c = Asc(Mid(file, i, 1))
    If c = 0 Then 
        content = content & VbCrLf
    ElseIf c > 3 Then
        content = content & Chr(c)
    end If
Next

Dim items : items = Split(content, VbCrLf)

For i = 0 To Ubound(items)
    If Instr(LCase(items(i)), "appname") > 0 Then Wscript.Echo items(i+1)
Next

Set oFile = Nothing
```

Copy the `shortcuts.vcf` file into the same folder as this code and then from a command line type:

```
cscript steam.vbs > output.txt
```

Open the output in any text editor and you'll see a list of all the game shortcuts you have added.

Comment: there must be something wrong with the file because all I get is an empty output file or none at all. both of your methods plus the visual basic script method don't work. I even saved the `vdf` file as `.txt` - same thing: empty output. I have updated the original question and attached the `vdf` file to it, it does not contain any personal information. I must be doing something wrong

Comment: @Phil Looks like your `shortcuts.vdf` file has additional characters before the `AppName` and it is was in lowercase. I've modified the `If` statement and can now get a list of 353 items. You've got some good games :)

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Now since I don't understand very much about visual basic I don't really understand the code I just copy pasted it, which one shouldn't do I guess but I will try to comprehend what it does exactly. I also double clicked on the script as I thought that might work too but it only shows me a windows titled `Windws Script Host` listing every title with an OK option to click. I terminated the process using the Task Manager.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it and please don’t forget to tick that it’s been answered. If you’d like, I can modify the code so that when you double-click on the file it creates a `shortcuts.txt` file containing the list of games.

Comment: Thanks! I will do that - you know what I'm gonna research how to do that myself as a bit of learning :)

Comment: Have fun! To be honest, I’d probably look at powershell or python as vbscript is a dying language.

Comment: Looking at the file with the Atom Editor I see a square before each Exe, is this square the `VbCrLf` character? The Carriage return character? It can't be just a space character because some games have spaces in their titles.

Answer (score 0):

There's an unofficial [vdf python module](https://github.com/ValvePython/vdf) for parsing Valve's vdf files. With it, parsing and writing out a csv with all the names is very simple:

```python
import vdf

def print_names(shortcut_file_path):
    with open(shortcut_file_path, "rb") as f:
        shortcuts = vdf.binary_load(f)

    with open('c:/scratch/shortcuts.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write('Game Name\n')
        for k, v in shortcuts["shortcuts"].items():
            appname = v.get("appname")
            print(appname)
            f.write(appname + '\n')

print_names("C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/userdata/149576161/config/shortcuts.vdf")
```

To see all the available fields (aside from "appname"), replace the `print` line with `import pprint; pprint.pprint(v); break`

Like other python modules, install vdf with `pip install vdf`.